# Responsive section by columns

Tags: html, css, responsive

im trying to make a responsive section.

this is how i want it to look in **desktop**:

```
+---+---+---+--------------+
| 3 | 2 | 1 |       A      |    <- this is right one
+---+---+---+--------------+
```

an this is how it should look in **mobile** view:

```
+-----------+
|     A     |
+---+---+---+   <- this is right one
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

tried some tutorials too but every time ending up to this:

```
+-----------+
|     A     |
+-----------+
|     1     |
+-----------+   <- this is wrong one
|     2     |
+-----------+
|     3     |
+-----------+
```

hope visualization helps.

i tried to make a section with 2 columns. first column has letter in it. second column has a inner section with 3 column and each column has a number in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be done with grid.

one way would be to make nested grid, but simpler if you specify exactly position start and end.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 1fr;
  gap: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(29, 145, 229, 0.5);
}

#div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  background-color: rgba(1, 16, 21, 0.5);
}

#div3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  background-color: rgba(66, 202, 43, 0.5);
}

#A {
  grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
  background-color: rgba(53, 69, 26, 0.5);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #div3 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    background-color: rgba(143, 196, 214, 0.5);
  }
  #div2 {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
    background-color: rgba(126, 56, 58, 0.5);
  }
  #A {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4;
    background-color: rgba(158, 192, 23, 0.5);
  }
  #div1 {
    grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
    background-color: rgba(9, 129, 51, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
  <div id="div3">3</div>
  <div id="A">A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

HTML:

```
 <div class="parent">
    <div>3</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>A</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .parent {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .parent>div {
        flex: 1;
        border: 1px dotted black;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }

    .parent>div:last-child {
        flex: 5;
    }
```

You can change your media query as per your requirement.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
        .parent {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .parent>div:last-child {
            flex-basis: 100%;
            order: -1;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

using media screen and flexbox

HTML CODE

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="3">1</div>
  <div class="2">2</div>
  <div class="1">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container div {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
.container .A {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 50vh;
  }
}
```